# Executing Console application from CMD

Tags: c#, cmd, console-application

I have a lot of functions written in c# console application for illustrating
different set of codes. Say if i have functions like writeXML(), readXML(), 
writeText(), ReadText()

My Main() function will open the command prompt and now,
Is it possible to go to cmd and execute a particular function, one by one to 
illustrate and show the output of each ???

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What do you have a problem with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short the ans is a no..
but yes you can use `reflection` combined with `Console.ReadLine()` to do what you wanna do
something like this

```
while(true)
{
 var cmd = Console.ReadLine();
 var methodInfo = from m in (classObject).GetType().GetMethods() where m.Name == cmd;
 methodInfo.Invoke(classObject, new object[] { /* arguments to method */ });
}
```

NOTE:-the code i have given here is just a pseudo code and not valid but you will be able to make your way through once you start applying it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/01/30/roslyn-ctp-introduces-interactive-code-for-c.aspx) for interactive C# is an option?

It even has a [scripting API](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/11/16/the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx), but I am quite pleased with this [standalone Roslyn REPL](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/Details/12704) (and now there is also a [more elegant GUI](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/Details/12710)).